# How to run my python script when the sunOS is start booting

Tags: python, solaris, sunos, s

I copied the script (server.py) to /etc/init.d folder.

```
chmod 0744 /etc/init.d/server.py
chown root:sys /etc/init.d/server.py 
cd /etc/init.d
ln server.py /etc/rc2.d/Sserver.py
ln server.py /etc/rc0.d/Kserver.py
ls /etc/init.d/*server.py /etc/rc2.d/*server.py /etc/rc0.d/*server.py
```

(able to see the links created in step 5 and 6)

then I power off the sunOS , and started. But unfortunately I can't see the server.py is running. I checked it using ps -ef.

I wanted to know ,is there anything I missed here or any other configuration steps were missing

Comment: SunOS! As far as I remember, startup scripts used to have a 2-digit number following the `S` in their names, e.g. `S90nfsd`. Also, you'll need a proper Python shebang as the first line of your `server.py` if it is even possible to use a non-bash script.

Comment: I modified as, 
/etc/init.d/server.py    /etc/rc0.d/K90server.py  /etc/rc2.d/S90server.py 
and also added Python shebang as   #!/usr/bin/env python3 
but there is no improvement, can't see the server.py running after reboot sunOS

Comment: I can't remember that far back, but try looking at some other startup scripts. I think they get called with a parameter of 'start' or 'stop' so you may need to wrap your Python inside a `bash` script to handle that... or hopefully someone else can remember...

Comment: Use cron for start up when booting.

Comment: @toyotaSupra That's what init.d scripts are for.  Abusing cron like that is a Linux thing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm pretty sure Solaris run-control scripts are *sourced* by `/bin/sh`, and, unlike Linux, there's no conflation of `sh` and `bash` on Solaris.  And the name of the script here sure looks like a Python script - which, as you imply, probably won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the correct symlinks, your script in `/etc/init.d` will be called with `sys.argv[1] == 'start'` upon startup and `sys.argv[1] == 'stop'` upon shutdown. Make sure it works with these values.

To debug this further, write a debug script `/etc/init.d/mydebug` containing this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec >>/tmp/mydebug.log
echo
echo ---
date
id
for ARG in "$@"; do echo "arg: $ARG"; done
echo ENV:
env | sort
echo
```

, do the *chmod*, the *chown*, create the symlinks, reboot, and check the contents of the file `/tmp/mydebug.log`.

---

@AndrewHenle has commented that on SunOS the run-control scripts are sourced by `/bin/sh`. To accommodate this, start your Python script like this (and then follow with Python source code):

```
#!/bin/sh
""":"; exec python -- "$0" "$@" #"""
```

Replace `python` above with `/usr/local/bin/python` or wherever your Python interpreter is.

This will make it work in both cases: if it's exec()ed and if it's sourced by `/bin/sh`.

---

Based on your comment, SunOS is running the *mydebug* script at startup. So there is a problem with *server.py* only (not with *mydebug*).

You mention starting *server.py* with `#!/usr/bin/python`. This doesn't work if run-control scripts are sourced by `/bin/sh`. Instead of this line, please use the 2 lines I've recommended above instead. Don't forget to change `python` to `/usr/local/bin/python` if your Python interpreter is there.

As a preparation, run this as root:

```
chown root:sys /etc/init.d/server.py 
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/server.py
```

To diagnose this further, run this from the command-line as root:

```
# Run the following command as root.
cd / && /usr/bin/env -i _AST_FEATURES="UNIVERSE - att" _INIT_PREV_LEVEL=S _INIT_RUN_LEVEL=3 _INIT_RUN_NPREV=0 _INIT_UTS_ISA=i386 _INIT_UTS_MACHINE=i86pc _INIT_UTS_NODENAME=t8a1 _INIT_UTS_PLATFORM=i86pc _INIT_UTS_RELEASE=5.11 _INIT_UTS_SYSNAME=SunOS _INIT_UTS_VERSION=11.4.42.111.0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL= LC_COLLATE= LC_CTYPE= LC_MESSAGES= LC_MONETARY= LC_NUMERIC= LC_TIME= PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin /bin/sh /etc/init.d/server.py start; echo "Exit code: $?"
```

The command above is equivalent to what's happening at SunOS system startup. But in here you will get a direct error message, and you can retry it quickly, without having to restart your system.

Success looks like this: the server.py program starts the server in the background and exits successfully (you see `Exit code: 0`). If you see anything else (e.g. a different exit code, an error message, server.py doesn't exit quickly), then that's an error which you have to fix in your own code (*server.py*). You may want to ask a separate question about that on StackOverflow.

Comment: Note, though, that the OP's script is `/etc/init.d/server.py`, which is likely a Python script.  Which probably won't work when sourced by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I've added a workaround for run-control scripts being sourced by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @pts , still not able to see script is running when sunOS booting.
Tuesday, July 25, 2023 at  9:31:01 AM CEST
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
arg: start
ENV:
_=*1108*/usr/bin/env
_AST_FEATURES=UNIVERSE - att
_INIT_PREV_LEVEL=S
_INIT_RUN_LEVEL=3
_INIT_RUN_NPREV=0
_INIT_UTS_ISA=i386
_INIT_UTS_MACHINE=i86pc
_INIT_UTS_NODENAME=t8a1
_INIT_UTS_PLATFORM=i86pc
_INIT_UTS_RELEASE=5.11
_INIT_UTS_SYSNAME=SunOS
_INIT_UTS_VERSION=11.4.42.111.0
A__z="*SHLVL
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
LC_COLLATE=
LC_CTYPE=
LC_MESSAGES=
LC_MONETARY=
LC_NUMERIC=
LC_TIME=
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1

Comment: @pts
also added a line like this inside /etc/init.d/server.py 
#!/usr/bin/python 
permission are like this
-rwx-wx-wx   3 root     sys           45 Jul 24 13:34 server.py
-rwxr--r--   3 root     sys          125 Jul 25 08:58 mydebug

links are, 
/etc/init.d/server.py  /etc/rc0.d/K05SERVER   /etc/rc2.d/S05SERVER 
do this links also have the same source code as server.py?

Comment: Thank you for posting to output of *mydebug*. Based on that I've extended my answer.